# how to map database keys to Strings & display the text assigned to each key on UI screen?

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

In firebase db I am passing the keys as all , promotions ,etc. But on UI i want to display "show all notifications" instead of just "all".
Here I want to show-> if  key = all,then text to be shown is "show all alerts".

```
 void alerts() async {
    await _ref.child(widget.id).child("alerts").update({
      'all': true,
      'Promotions': true,
      'milestone': true,
      'email': true,
      'SMS': true,
    }).then((_) {
      print('Updated data node');
    });
  }
```

Comment: Could you rephrase your question?

Comment: I rephrased, please have a look. Let me know if you need more clarity.

Comment: I understand the question now. I'll add an answer shortly.

Comment: Thanks in advance, Sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can get the data from the database using the [.once](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/Query/once.html) method and then you can loop through the Map from the result and get the [key](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.5/dart-core/MapEntry/key.html).
2. You can then [interpolate](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#strings) the key in a string to be displayed in the UI.

Here is an example:

```dart
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String id;

  const HomeScreen({Key key, @required this.id}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  final DatabaseReference _ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();

  Map data;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _ref.child(widget.id).child('alerts').once().then((DataSnapshot snapshotData) {
      setState(() {
        data = snapshotData.value;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: data == null
          ? Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            )
          : Column(
              children: data.entries
                  .map((mapEntry) => Text('Show ${mapEntry.key} notifications'))
                  .toList(),
            ),
    );
  }
}
```